# Cross reference to an element of a numbered list without the dot and space that follows the number

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, cross-reference

---

I have a document with a numbered list where the numbers are followed by a dot and a space.

When I cross reference to an element of the list, I want only the number to appear, without the dot and the space.

I cannot get the desired behaviour. If I use only a dot after the number I can get the desired behaviour. But it seems clumsy to have no space between the dot and following text.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem arose because of **typing** the space after the dot.

This was done by clicking

- the downward arrow in the Multilevel List icon
- Define New Multilevel List...

Doing this opened the window named "Define new Multilevel list". Then I added a space in "Entering formatting for number:". This was my mistake. Whenever anything else that a single dot is added to the number in "Entering formatting for number:", que character (e.g. a space) will appear as part of the cross reference.

When I erased the space from "Entering formatting for number:", and chose "Space" from the drop-down menu under "Follow number with:", the problem was solved. Now, when I cross reference an item of the list, I do not get even the dot that follows the number by default.

In summary, use the "Follow number with:" drop-down menu from the "Define new Multilevel list" if you want to have a space after the dot that follows the number of a numbered list.